# How to get width of content in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get the width of the content, do some calculations on it, and present a badge.

```
let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

const tabWidth = tab.width;
```

But if I have devtools open anchored to the right, I get that as part of the width. How can I get the non-devtools size - the real size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
    function getWidth() {
        var msg = {
            a: document.body.clientWidth,
            b: document.body.scrollWidth,
            c: window.innerWidth,
            d: window.pageXOffset,
            e: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width,
            f: document.body.offsetWidth
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    var tab = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab[0].id},
        function: getWidth
    }, () =>  {
        console.log('script injected')
    })
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    console.table(msg)
})
```